# Java: Trouble converting String to long

Tags: java

I'm having a problem parsing String to long. The string in question is a number that's preceded with spaces. For example: "  35".

NetBeans threw this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "  35"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:578)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
at Sis1.main(Sis1.java:75)
/Users/michaeladrian39/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I want to parse the String "35" without the spaces to long. How to fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to parse string "35" but try to parse string " 35" that has extra space. Remove it by calling (for example) `trim()`:

```
Integer.parseInt(str.trim())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the space before 35. Remove the spaces and all should work.

Comment: If your string is dynamic, then call string.trim() and then passit to Long.parseLong() -- as syggested by AlexR.

Answer (score 0):

```
String as = "6767";
      long vb = Long.valueOf(as).longValue();
      System.out.println(vb);
```

hope my code helps. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Long.parseLong(String s, int radix) documentation states that the string 's' should not contain a non-digi character, Here's the excerpt from javadoc.

> An exception of type NumberFormatException is thrown if any of the
>   following situations occurs:
>
> - The first argument is null or is a string of length zero.
> - The radix is either smaller than Character.MIN_RADIX or larger than      Character.MAX_RADIX.
> - Any character of the string is not a digit of the specified radix,       except that the first character may be a minus sign '-' ('\u002d') or 
>     plus sign '+' ('\u002B') provided that the string is longer than
>     length 1.
> - The value represented by the string is not a value of type long.

Examples:

```
 parseLong("0", 10) returns 0L
 parseLong("473", 10) returns 473L
 parseLong("+42", 10) returns 42L
 parseLong("-0", 10) returns 0L
 parseLong("-FF", 16) returns -255L
 parseLong("1100110", 2) returns 102L
 parseLong("99", 8) throws a NumberFormatException
 parseLong("Hazelnut", 10) throws a NumberFormatException
 parseLong("Hazelnut", 36) returns 1356099454469L
```

String.trim() should work for you (as AlexR mentioned).